# Swift iOS version availability - check from * to iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried to use such check to apply some code that should works only on previous versions of iOS before iOS 13 and it doesn't work correctly i.e. it is executed on iOS 13

```
if #available(*, iOS 12) { }
```

I make a workaround like this

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    /// Do nothing here
} else {

}
```

But i have additional curly braces block

Answer (score 4):

You can use guard statement

```
guard #available(iOS 13.0, *) else {
  // Code for earlier iOS versions
  return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the currentVersion of your OS using:

```
UIDevice.current.systemVersion
```

Using this you can easily create your own method.

```
func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, 
     options: NSString.CompareOptions.numeric) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5.6 (Xcode 13.3+), you can use `#unavailable` condition.

```swift
if #unavailable(iOS 13) {
  // This code will run on iOS 12.* and earlier
}
```

This is the proposal for reference: [SE-0290](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0290-negative-availability.md).