# KMM-iOS - How can I check ios version run time

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform

In swift, the code check availability of APIs on different version.

```swift
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            // Do something for iOS 14.0 and later
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

How can I implement it in Kotlin Multi Platform (iOS)?

I can't find the way to check APIs iOS availability in KMM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ios-specific sourceset, you can try something like this:

```kotlin
import platform.UIKit.UIDevice

// Etc

fun systemVersion() = UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion
```

I haven't tried this, but got the Swift version from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58080004/227313 and that's the Kotlin version of how you'd call it.

If you want to get that value in common code, you can do an expect/actual function.

Comment: Nice @Kevin, it's worked for me.